# String search in a file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I've a file named test

```
# cat test
192.168.171.3   840 KB   /var/opt
192.168.171.3    83 MB   /var
192.168.171.3     2 KB   /var/tmp
192.168.171.3  1179 KB   /var/opt
192.168.171.3    65 MB   /opt/var/dump
192.168.171.3    15 MB   /opt/varble
192.168.171.3     3 MB   /var
```

I want to search for entries that has only /var and not any other variations of it such as /opt/var or /var/tmp. I tried grep '^/var$' test or awk, but it doesn't work.

```
# grep '^/var$' test
#
# awk '/^\/var$/' test
#
```

Please help !

++Sorry for the pain... already got it sorted, but thanks for all your answers !++

Answer (score 2):

This grep command should work:

```
grep " /var$" file

192.168.171.3    83 MB   /var
192.168.171.3     3 MB   /var
```

Using awk:

```
awk '$4=="/var"' file
192.168.171.3    83 MB   /var
192.168.171.3     3 MB   /var
```

Comment: Your first regex only works with spaces as column separators, it fails with tabs. It also fails when there is a path like `/random/with space /var`. Yeah, unlikely, but still.

Comment: @user2719058: This grep will work for both tab/space: **`grep "[[:space:]]/var$" file`**

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the following:

```
grep -w ^/var file
```

The -w flag will match strings that form whole words, and the ^ will force it to match the start of a line.